# Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build the cordova project. But build fail with following message. how to fix this?

```
C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\cordova_dev\cordova\hello>cordova build
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Nuwanst\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 32.653 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**What went wrong**

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\Nuwanst\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2
```

**Try**

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Comment: please try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use reference of this link for set ANDROID_Home path http://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/

and make sure is your sdk path is correct or not in

1. File -> project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left -> SDK Location
3. SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

Answer (score 0):

It says you do not have API 23 installed. Make sure you install API 23 or you can change that to the API number which is installed in your system.
You can do that in your config.xml file. Just find and change the values in lines below.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```